# MySQL multicolumn primary key

Tags: mysql

What is the maximum columns number for a multicolumn primary key (MySQL)? Does it depend on column data type or engine?

Comment: its 16 in sql server 2008.. dont know abt mysql

Comment: [This article is from 2006](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/17/max-key-length-in-mysql/) and it says the max length for primary key is 1000 bytes.  I am not sure if that has changed since.

Comment: I think the limits are 1000 bytes for MyiSAM and 3072 for InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it depends on storage engine.

- [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html):

  > The maximum number of columns per index is 16. The maximum key length
  >   is 1000 bytes. This can also be changed by changing the source and
  >   recompiling. For the case of a key longer than 250 bytes, a larger key
  >   block size than the default of 1024 bytes is used.
- [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html):

  > The InnoDB internal maximum key length is 3500 bytes, but MySQL itself
  >   restricts this to 3072 bytes. This limit applies to the length of the
  >   combined index key in a multi-column index.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

someone tried to create a PK with 2 columns and received this error:
**"Specified key was too long; max key length is 1024 bytes"** so it looks that the maximum it's 1024 bytes, it doesn't matter the columns number what really matter is the var type and the space assign it.

I have seen some examples like this:

```
create table OS_PROPERTYENTRY (entity_name VARCHAR(125) not null, entity_id BIGINT not null,

entity_key VARCHAR(255) not null date_val DATETIME, primary key (entity_name, entity_id, entity_key))
```

where

125 * (3 bytes) + 255 * (3 bytes) + 1 * (8 bytes) = 1148 bytes. So it's not possible to create a PK.

take a look here, they talk about it: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-2783