# Limit for Multicolumn Index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

For multi-column indexes, is there a limit on the number of columns? How many columns of integer can be included in the index?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried looking into the documents? It actually depends on the engine you are using.

For `MyISAM` the limit is : 16 columns

For `InnoDB` the limit is: `3072 bytes`

References:
[The MyISAM Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)

[Limits on InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

Another similar SO post:

[MySQL multicolumn primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838562/mysql-multicolumn-primary-key)