# Why Hibernate can not create table?

Tags: hibernate, mariadb

I have the Java SE application with Hibernate of following versions:
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}

It fail to initialisation: entityManagerF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mgr");

which cause the following exception:

```
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at entities.HibernateUtil.initialize(HibernateUtil.java:64)
    at entities.HibernateUtil.getEntityManager(HibernateUtil.java:49)
    at com.company.RunS.<clinit>(RunS.java:30)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 104
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:536)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:891)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:795)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 17 more
```

and tables can't be created thus. Can anybody tell me how to make Hibernate works?

Comment: Share the DDL, looks like there is error in syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Type=MyISAM Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937789/mysql-type-myisam-error)

Comment: It has errot: at the end of DDL there is ") type=MyISAM" but must be ")ENGINE=MyISAM" as I know. But I have no idea how to fix this error, it is autogenerated script and I have <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
. I have "INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found" in logs , probably this play?

Comment: @Jens Hibernate autogenerates DDL scripts , could you tell me how to force it to use proper syntax?

Comment: @Catherine Which dialect do you use?

Comment: @Jens org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
But I have: "INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found" 
Plan to fix this first

Comment: @Catherine: good idea ;)

Comment: @Catherine please use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` (see the 5 in the middle)

Comment: @Jens thank you. But I have "Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes"
 in this case

Comment: @Catherine what have you changed?

Comment: @Jens hibernate.dialect

Comment: @Catherine can you show the entity regarding to the table?

Comment: @Jens I can't paste in initial post because of size limitations. In short I have complex primary key  consists of four "varchar(255)" fileds

Comment: @Catherine can you use a technical key (autoincrement)?

Comment: @Jens No I need this complex key ultimately

Comment: @Catherine can you shorten it to varchar(250)?

Comment: @Jens basically it works - to shorten to varchar(40) but I strongly prefer to rise up the key length limitation. It is sensitive primary key

Comment: @Catherine the key Limitation in mysql for myisam is 1000 Bytes. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838562/mysql-multicolumn-primary-key

Comment: @Jens I need to switch to InnoDB thus ... could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @Catherine use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect

Answer (score 0):

`... syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' ...` is the problem.

That is old syntax.  Change `type` to `engine` to solve your problem.

If Hibernate is generating that wrong syntax, then upgrade it!